# Как добавить пункт расширенный заголовок для шаблона на MODX Evolution v1.2?

Tags: cms, modx

Как добавить пункт расширенный заголовок для шаблона на MODX Evolution v1.2?

На одном шаблоне есть он.

[image: На одном шаблоне есть он.]

А на другом его нет.

[image: А на другом его нет.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MODx Evolution плагин ManagerManager позволяет настраивать внешний вид страницы редактирования ресурса.
В чанке "mm_rules" описание конфигурации ManagerManager-а для отображений страниц относительно их id или шаблона. 
Поищите в чанке этом функцию такого типа:

```
mm_hideFields('longtitle', '', '<id_ресурса_где_отсутствует_longtitle>');
```

Детальнее в документации: http://i--gu.ru/managermanager